# How can we do video recording using VNC

Tags: c++, networking, video, vnc

How can we do video recording using VNC? I want to record all the session. we have multiple clients and server. So efficiency is important too.

Anyone has any idea of some opensource project which can handle this. I can think of *vncrec* only but haven't used it. So nyone who used this project.

Comment: Recording complete sessions from multiple clients is probably quite processor / network intensive. Did you consider taking screenshots at a certain interval? Or make the client record itself and automatically upload the result to the server (at logout)?

Comment: Do you want to do this programatically or are you looking for a tool to automate the process?

Comment: basically i want to record all the sessions. So whenever a session between server and client(1 or many) starts, I can record server desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.debian.org/HowtoRecordVNC) is some info (Debian centric) about recording and transcoding VNC sessions into movie files including how to use vncrec and other options.